# String to wstring conversion on OS X

Tags: c++, unicode, locale, diacritics, wstring

I'm trying to convert a C++ string to a wstring.
I found the following code, that seems to deal with accents, which is what I'm looking for.

```
std::wstring widen(const std::string& s)
{
    std::vector<wchar_t> buffer(s.size());
    std::locale loc("fr_FR");
    std::use_facet< std::ctype<wchar_t> >(loc).widen(s.data(), s.data() + s.size(), &buffer[0]);

    return std::wstring(&buffer[0], buffer.size());
}
```

[Source](http://cpp.developpez.com/faq/cpp/?page=strings#STRINGS_unicode)

Unfortunately, the code crashes for any other *loc* value than C or POSIX. This problem has already been discussed, without success, here: [std::locale breakage on MacOS 10.6 with LANG=en_US.UTF-8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1745045/stdlocale-breakage-on-macos-10-6-with-langenus-utf-8), [here](http://trac.macports.org/ticket/15653) or [here](http://lists.apple.com/archives/darwin-dev/2008/Mar/msg00015.html).

Is there any workaround or an other way to do this ?

Comment: Can you fix the title? It reads as if you want to convert wstring -> string. Your problem description however is string -> wstring.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest would be

```
std::wstring w( s.begin(), s.end() );
```

... but to preserve accents you'd need [codecvt](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/locale/codecvt/) however, this [example](http://stdcxx.apache.org/doc/stdlibref/codecvt.html#sec12) might be useful.

Comment: As the example uses 'std::locale loc (std::cout.getloc (), new ex_codecvt);' won't it just bug the same way ?