# How to use wstring and wcout to output Chinese words in Xcode?

Tags: c++, xcode, macos

I try to run the code blow in Xcode 4.2:

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    locale loc("chs");
    locale::global(loc);

    wstring text(L"你好");
    wcout << text << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I got a error "Thread 1:signal SIGABRT".

Can you Tell me why the error happen or how to use `wstring` and `wcout` to output the Chinese words?

Comment: @CarlNorum: What is a backtrack? where can i find it?

Comment: Sounds like you need to learn to use a [debugger](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debugger).

Comment: @CarlNorum: I usually use a VS Debugger. I think you mean the "Call Stack" in VS debug?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't. Mac, like other Unix systems, uses UTF8 while Windows uses "Unicode" (UTF-16).

You can print that perfectly well on Mac by using `string` and `cout` instead of `wstring` and `wcout`.

ADDENDUM

This sample works great. Compile with g++ and run as-is.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(int arg, char **argv)
{
    string text("汉语");
    cout << text << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: +1 I think you should have been awarded the *correct answer*!

Comment: No problem. Your answer was pretty much identical, no worries.

Answer (score 1):

The crash is coming from the call to `locale()`.  This [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1745045/stdlocale-breakage-on-macos-10-6-with-lang-en-us-utf-8) seems related.

As mentioned by [Mahmoud Al-Qudsi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17027/mahmoud-al-qudsi), you don't need it as you can use UTF-8 in a normal `string` object:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    string text("你好");
    cout<<text<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Produces:

```
$ ./test
你好
```

**EDIT**: Oops, too late :)

Comment: Our development team gave up on using locale management on OS X. OS X (unlike all the other OSes out there now) was created in a post-unicode world. You don't need to fuss or worry about setting the locale and the encoding... but if you have software that already does that, there's a chance it may break as the locale libraries are.... buggy.

Comment: @MahmoudAl-Qudsi Localisation is something I think English-speaking developers (like me) find quite difficult; no longer can we just assume that the whole world speaks English :)  It's not an easy aspect of any development even when you get the technology working; you still need to employee people to translate your product into other languages.  That's something I am about to face myself, with some dread...

Comment: When I say "locale management" I was referring to the C/C++/System locale settings, only.